# ¿Cómo hacer que el Sub Menú al mostrarse no se coloque detrás de los demás elementos HTML?

Tags: css, html5, menú

Tengo un problema con el sub menú de mi barra de navegación, este al desplegarse se coloca detrás de los demás elementos HTML y quería que siempre el sub menú se muestre siempre delante.

Aquí la imagen :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzyST.png)

Codigo CSS :

```css
   #header {

    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;

   }

   ul, ol {
    list-style:none;
   }

   .navBar > li {
    background-color: #504188;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
   }

   .navBar li a {
    background-color:#504188;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px 15px;
    display:block;
   }

   .navBar li a:hover {
    background-color:#434343;
   }

   .navBar li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    min-width:170px;
   }

   .navBar li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
   }

   .navBar li ul li {
    position:relative;
   }

   .navBar li ul li ul {
    right:-140px;
    top:0px;
   }
```

Gracias de antemano, espero puedan ayudarme ya que llevo días con esto y no le encuentro solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes ponerle en el estilo CSS que le corresponda un 'z-index' superior al del resto. Ejemplo:

```
   .submenu{z-index:9999999999}
```

Comment: Con solo colocar 999 basta.

Comment: Por eso es puesto 'ejemplo:', y tantos 9 para que se vea claro, es probable que la clase sobre la que lo aplique no se llame '.submenu'. De hecho con poner un número que sea +1 al que tenga el elemento que debe ir debajo vale, tampoco tiene porqué ser 999.